# Integrate by parts elementary

Tags: calculus, integration

I have trouble integrating 
$$\int (1-e^{-\frac{1}{2}\phi^2 x}) x^{-1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\,dx$$, 
Could anyone show me a good way to do by hand? Assume $\phi>0$.

The answer obtained from mathematica is $-2^{-\frac{\alpha }{2}} \left(\phi ^2\right)^{\alpha /2} \Gamma \left(-\frac{\alpha }{2}\right)$

Comment: Is a *definite* Integral intended?

Comment: Whatever is the result, if it is independent of $x$, it must be a definite integral between bounds you do not tell about. What syntax did you enter in Mathematica ?

Answer (score 1):

You can let $\frac1 2\phi^2 x=y$,

You will then have something like: 
$$\int e^{-y}y^{-1-\alpha/2}dy=\Gamma(-\alpha/2)$$ if you have a boundary of the integral $0,\infty$.